# Qual a diferença entre os pronomes pessoais "vossa" ou "sua" antes de pronomes de tratamento?

Tags: pronomes

Muitas vezes, vemos pronomes pessoais antes de pronomes de tratamentos, como:

- **Vossa** excelência está bem?
- **Sua** excelência está bem?

Qual a diferença entre elas?

Comment: Vossa = você fala diretamente com a pessoa; Sua = você fala sobre a pessoa. Vossa Santidade está bem? (Falando para o Papa); Sua Santidade está bem? (Falando do Papa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como no exemplo que deste,

***"Vossa*** excelência" é como se deve dirigir à pessoa em questão, já
***"Sua*** excelência" é como se deve dirigir falando da pessoa, esta sendo uma terceira pessoa.

No exmplo "Vossa excelência está bem?", pergunta-se, imaginemos, ao presidente. No segundo exemplo "Sua excelência está bem?", presume-se que duas pessoas falam a repeito do dito presidente.
Isto acontece pois trata-se a pessoa por "vós" (daí "vossa") e, quando se fala dela, por "ele" ou "ela" (daí "sua").

Espero que tenha ficado claro :).

Comment: Não, eu não usaria "vossa excelência" ao me dirigir ao meu presidente.